# Equation in ring Q[x]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Here is an abstract algebra problem :

Solve the equation (in $ℚ[x]$) :
$$f(x)(2x^3 + 3x^2 + 7x + 1) + g(x)(5x^4 + x + 1) = x + 3$$

From your comments, I tried to apply extended euclidean algo but it ends up with completely unlikely reminders and quotient. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong before I continue with these terrible calculations ?[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your post to include how you found that, so that we can locate your mistake.

Comment: The standard method to solve such equation is by the extended Euclidean algorithm - see the linked dupe.  Here the gcd $=1$ so it is solvable.

Comment: @Nicrotte just as Bill said. The gcd is one. Use the extended to find the bezout-coeffiecents such that $a(x)(2x^3+3x^2+7x+1)+b(x)(5x^4+x+1)=1$, then multiply both sides by x+3 and you're done.