# Extended Euclidian algorithm for polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

this question follows one from yesterday that got deleted because it was a duplicate.

The problem was about solving this equation (in $ℚ[x]$) :

$$f(x)(2x^3 + 3x^2 + 7x + 1) + g(x)(5x^4 + x + 1) = x + 3$$

Members of the community answered yesterday that the gcd is 1 which implies that the equation is solvable.

Based on their advices I tried to use Extended Euclidian Algo for polynomials to find the Bezout coeff such that $a(x)(2x^3+3x^2+7x+1)+b(x)(5x^4+x+1) = 1$.

But after very long calculations, I couldn't find 1 as the last reminder but $\frac{26684375}{261662976} \simeq 0.102$. I hope it's a miscalculation, but I'm lost.

Can you tell me how members that answered me yesterday found 1 as the gcd that quickly ?

Thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of work as it is bad for accessibility. Instead, use Latex.

Comment: Is the following question the "one from yesterday": [Equation in ring $Q[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4829236/89922)? That question is not deleted.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes it's this one. I thought it was deleted sorry.

Comment: As explained in the linked dupe, gcds that are *constant* $\,c\in \Bbb Q\,$ are *normalized* to $1$ by convention. Generally we can ignore nonzero constant (= unit) factors when computing polynomial gcds (over a field) since $\,f\mid cg\iff f\mid g.\ \ $

Comment: Thanks @BillDubuque ! Does it mean that i can ignore the constant and act as if I obtained 1 ? Or do I have to multiply my whole last equation by the inverse of the constant I obtained (on both sides of the equation) ?

Comment: $a\,f+b\,g = c\iff  c^{-1}a\,f + c^{-1}b\,g = 1$. By convention we refer to $1$ as "the"  gcd of $f,g.\,$ More generally we normalize the gcd so that it is monic (lead coef $c= 1),\,$ see the linked dupe.